# Locate and remove "hidden" swing components place in Netbeans editor

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have managed to collect quite a few `Swing` components on my `JFrame` that I placed with the editor but "removed" though they still appear in the generated code.

[image]

Though I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove them, from the designer I cannot select any of these components

[image]

Is there a way to remove these?

Comment: Such are the drawbacks of using a GUI designer tool instead of writing the code manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the components and delete them from the Navigator window when the "Design" is selected in the current editor window. The Navigator window should be the window that is usually in the bottom left corner under the project window. It shows a tree that you may have to expand some nodes in the tree to find the components of interest. You can select a whole list of components at a time and delete them from there.

[image: Screenshot with bunch of JButtonGroups selected for deletion.]

Comment: What if those components are not listed in the Navigator? ('Other components' is also empty)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I can't answer this without a working example of how one creates components not listed in the Navigator.  If you want open a new question so you can describe that more fully.

Comment: As usual, when something is weird, restart NetBeans and it's fixed.